# How to publish this C# Source Generator with dependencies on Nuget?

Tags: c#, nuget, sourcegenerators

I've created a C# source generator, and would like to publish it to Nuget.

But I run into warnings/errors such as:

- `Some target frameworks declared in the dependencies group of the nuspec and the lib/ref folder do not have exact matches in the other location. Consult the list of actions below: - Add lib or ref assemblies for the netstandard2.0 target framework`
- `An instance of analyzer Cosmogenesis.Generator.CosmosGenerator cannot be created from [..]\Cosmogenesis.Generator.dll : Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..` (or Version=2.0.0.0 depending on what I'm trying)

There are a few resources explaining how, but none seem to work in my exact scenario, which is:

- `Cosmogenesis.Core`

  - .NET Standard 2.1
  - Not depended on by the generator, but the generated source code depends on it
- `Cosmogenesis.Generator` (published on Nuget as just `Cosmogenesis`)

  - .NET Standard 2.0
  - This is the source generator

Ideally, I'd like to be able to just install `Cosmogenesis` from Nuget and it would automatically bring in `Cosmogenesis.Core` along with the generator.

[Use functionality from NuGet packages](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md#use-functionality-from-nuget-packages) <-- explains my scenario (except for differing .net standard requirements).  ....And as a side question: Why does it have code to check if an assembly is referenced if it's explaining how to make it be automatically referenced?....

Anyway...

Here is [Cosmogenesis on Github](https://github.com/joshlang/Cosmogenesis)

`Cosmogenesis.Core` is published without any trouble.

`Cosmogenesis.Generator` is published using this [.csproj](https://github.com/joshlang/Cosmogenesis/blob/master/Cosmogenesis.Generator/Cosmogenesis.Generator.csproj) as well

It works.  However, the consumer needs to reference BOTH packages.  I'd like them to only need to reference one package.

When I add `<IncludeBuildOutput>false</IncludeBuildOutput>` (as per tutorial above), on build I get this warning: `Some target frameworks declared...` [see above].  If I ignore it and publish it anyway, when I consume the package in a project and build it, the generator does not run and I get this warning: `An instance of analyzer...` [see above].

When I add `<PackageReference Include="Cosmogenesis.Core" Version="0.0.1" />` (as per tutorial above), I get an error.  The generator is .NET Standard 2.0 while the .Core package is 2.1.  The error is: `error NU1202: Package Cosmogenesis.Core 0.0.1 is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Package Cosmogenesis.Core 0.0.1 supports: netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)`.  Understandable.

When I set the generator project to 2.1 to fix the mismatch, no warnings appear while building, however the consumer again gets the `An instance of analyzer...` error.  [C# Source Generators - Write code that writes code - David Wengier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pqLs7X6Cr6s&t=1280s) says they *have* to be .net standard 2.0.

This is my first nuget package.  And my first source generator.  Can anyone advise?

EDIT: I'm 75% sure a solution to [this roslyn github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/49641) would solve my problem here.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: There are lots of open issues on this ATM and no solution in sight. See https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/17775